# Why did the Colombians have the coke on them when they ambushed Tony?

Tags: plot-explanation, scarface

Why did the Colombians have the coke on them when they ambushed Tony in *Scarface*? They never showed it to him to lure him in or lower his defenses, just told him it was nearby before attacking him. Why bother bringing it at all?